# Class xx was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two databases for my application so I put the entities in two separate folders to simplify things.

```
Entity/  
   Local/  
      User.php
      Foo.php
   Remote/
      Bar.php
```

but I have an error 500 that I don't understand at the time of connection

```sh
[2020-09-03 17:10:58] request.CRITICAL:
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "The class 'App\Entity\Local\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces " at /www/myapp/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 23 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\Persistence\\Mapping\\MappingException(code: 0): The class 'App\\Entity\\Local\\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces  at /www/myapp/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:23)"} []
```

Here is my doctrine.yml configuration

```yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: local
        connections:
            local:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            remote:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_MS)%'
                charset: 'UTF-8'
                wrapper_class: App\Connections\ConnectionRemote
                mapping_types:
                    timestamp: string
                    xml: string
                schema_filter: $sales$
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: local
        entity_managers:
            local:
                connection: local
                mappings:
                    local:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Local'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Local'
                        alias: local
                    AnotherBundle: ~
            remote:
                connection: remote
                mappings:
                    remote:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Remote'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Remote'
                        alias: remote
```

Even stranger, if I refresh my page, I am well connected and the error doesn't come back...
Even crazier, it works very well in dev mode

Comment: Might try a "bin/console cache:clear"  Sometimes composer dump-autoload is required as well though I don't think it is needed in this case.  If neither helps then I suspect it is the AnotherBundle causing the problem.

Comment: As @Cerad suggested you have to run the `composer dump-autoload` command (and then `bin/console cache:clear`) to update the namespaces mapping.

Comment: thx but no, these commands don't help. the problem is always there.

Comment: Just for kicks, try 'expanding' AnotherBundle into the various individual parameters.  I know something like dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/another-bundle ...' is a bit awkward to say the least but you should at least rule it out as a possible source of the problem.  You can also try a 'hard cache clear' by actually removing the var/cache directory.  If you still have trouble then consider creating a new project and then adding just code to reproduce the issue.  Might be something else going on.

Comment: no the problem appears even when I delete the second bundle. but I managed to isolate a little bit the source of the problem ; it looks like it's not the right ORM that is injected in the onSecurityInteractiveLogin (simply for update user last login datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a bug in Doctrine, it's the fact that it works in dev and not in prod that put me on the track of the solution.

I had dumped the dev and prod conf to compare the two versions and what I noticed was that `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` was set to **default** even though it is set to custom in `package/doctrine.yaml`.

so for the value to be really taken into account you must also set `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` in `prod/doctrine.yaml`

```yaml
doctrine:
   orm:
       default_entity_manager: local
```